# How to rotate character 90 degrees clockwise with a font otf?

Tags: itext, itextpdf

Recent, i bought a font type otf (*).

Look in this font, i see many glyphs which are rotated 90 degrees clockwise as below :

[image]

How to display character same as above (use ItextPdf) with font (*).

Comment: There's development being made in itext to fully support otf with rotated glyphs for vertical writting and other scripts but not yet.

Comment: :(. i 'll wait mr Bruno Lowagie confirm this.